# Azure Data Factory - Switch Activity - File name startsWith

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to create a Azure Data Factory pipeline which has to first format the source file and then call another pipeline. The pipeline would be triggered every time a new file is uploaded in the source blob storage. I want to re-use this pipeline for different source file formats.

For this I intend to use a Switch activity and based on the source file name, call corresponding Copy activity to create a formatted sink file. The issue is that the source files have standard prefixes but then have a timestamp, which means that file name would be different every time, something like:
File 1:
ABCDEF_1233
ABCDEF_2244
File 2:
UVWXYZ_1222
UVWXYX_2345

Can anyone help me understand how to do this?
I was thinking of using a Switch activity, and in the expression, use the @startsWith(triggerBody().fileName, ) and then in the CASE statements, I would like to provide the file name prefixes like ABCDEF, UVWXYZ etc. and then call a copy activity for each of the CASE statements.
But I am not sure how to specify the second argument in the startsWith() function.

Comment: Do all the filenames have an underscore in their filenames? If so, you could split the filename at that character and use it in the Switch activity.

The startsWith() function returns true or false, so that so not really help you with extracting the generic part of the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have the filename in a variable called filename. write expression like this to find out which file we are going to load.

Have a set variable activity and assign file prefix to another variable called prefix

```
@if(greater(indexof(filename),'ABCDEF'),0),'ABCDEF',if(greater(indexof(filename),'UVWXYZ'),0),'UVWXYZ'))
```

At the end of this set variable, your prefix will have either ABCDEF or UVWXYZ

Then, you can use a switch activity based on prefix variable and mention the cases as

1. ABCDEF
2. UVWXYZ

for each case, you can have a copy activity for doing related transforamtions.